# can I use current() function in XPath, outside of XSLT?

Tags: xml, xpath

This is my XML document:

```
<root>
  <bad>
    <id>13</id>
    <id>27</id>
  </bad>
  <books>
    <book id='5'/>
    <book id='7'/>
    <book id='13'/>
  </books>
</root>
```

Now I'm trying to select all books that are not "bad":

```
/root/books/book[not(/root/bad/id[.=@current()/@id])]
```

This doesn't work. I'm getting all books, while book no.13 should be excluded. It's not XSLT. It's just an XPath request (I'm with Java). What's wrong?

Comment: Note that even if current() worked, and even if you removed the spurious "@", it would give the wrong answer. In XSLT current() always refers to the context item for the XPath expression as a whole, which in this case is (probably) the document node, whereas you're looking for the context item "one level up", that is, the current book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `current()` function is only supported by XSLT. But there's no need to use `current()` here. You can get the result you want with the following expression:

```
/root/books/book[not(@id=/root/bad/id)]
```